# How do I auto-insert the date in to the ion-datetime if it's value is ""

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I have an ion-datetime in my app that must have a value in it.  My expected behaviour is the current time displays in the ion-datetime.  The user then can have ability to change the date after if he wishes after auto-input of the ion-datetime.  I have though about using *ngIf, but calling the autodate( index: number ) method from the template is a bad idea and would crash the App.

html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label position="stacked">Finding Start Date <span style="color:red" >*</span></ion-label>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-datetime 
      displayFormat="YYYY DD MMM" 
      placeholder="Select Date" name="{{itemNew.DateName}}" 
      [(ngModel)]="findingForm[n].DateInput" >
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <div *ngIf="findingForm[n].DateInput">
    date here
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!findingForm[n].DateInput" >
    no date here 
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

ts

```
async autodate( index: number ) {
  this.date = new Date();
  this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate() );
  this.findingForm[index].dateInput = this.date.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `name` attribute will be the same as the value of `[(ngModel)]`

For example:

```
  <ion-datetime name="date" [(ngModel)]="date" displayFormat="YYYY DD MMM"></ion-datetime>
```